# MySQL - query only records with the earliest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with dates and other data.

```
id | date_col     | more data
----------------------------
 1 | '2017-01-01' | 'xdfaev'
 2 | '2017-01-01' | 'aevere'
 3 | '2017-02-03' | 'eefeee'
 4 | '2017-02-03' | 'rhrrrr'
 5 | '2017-05-04' | 'tuqbfr'
```

I want to query just the records that hold the earliest date:

```
1 | '2017-01-01' | more data
2 | '2017-01-01' | more data
```

How do I query that if I don't know the earliest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- this is SQL code but should be similar/same for mySQL, syntax may differ slightly

```
Select FiledList
From Table where date_col = 
(select MIN(date_col)
From Table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select * from table where date_col = (select min(date_col) from table);
```